# Can a rake task be triggered via a rails interface?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zip, rake, paperclip

Or am I thinking about this wrong?  Basically, I want to be able to upload a zip file to a model, and after uploading I want to run a bunch of processes on it.  It would be nice to be able to do this from the back end/console, as well as have a way of triggering the actions via the rails front-end interface.

The idea here:

Gallery has collection.zip

Gallery has many children :item

collection.zip has information for each Item

I want to trigger a batch gallery.items.build process that will extract the information from the zip and use it to create the new items.  I thought about using a Paperclip::Processor for this task, but I have yet to find a lot of truly useful or comprehensive documentation on how that would work, and experimentation has only led to frustration and confusion.  I saw some people use rake tasks for this sort of thing, but I really don't want to have to use the console to do perform the task, and would really just like to have a button that says "Generate Gallery" that will run all the necessary tasks.

So, is there a way of doing this?  Would this be considered bad practice?  If so, is there another way that I should be approaching this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do want to know how to run a rake task from rails, Ryan Bates has an excellent free screencast that show you how.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background

Answer (score 4):

[`delayed_job`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [`resque`](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) are considered to be the best practices for background processing, rather than running a rake task.

The central idea behind both:

1. Batch scripts or code that needs to be run in background is kept in `lib`.
2. Jobs are serialized and stored to DB (or any persistence layer or queue that is supported. eg. [`Redis`](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) or [`Starling`](https://github.com/starling/starling)) during the request cycle.
3. Daemon that runs in background, will look for jobs in the queue and process them in various orders (say, priority or fifo etc)

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger a rake task from within rails, but I'd write the logic to unzip and process the zip file in a class or module. Then you could use that code in either place.

Comment: If I was to run a rake task in rails, how would that be implemented? Or would it be better to write this as a method inside the gallery model?

Comment: You'd be much better off writing methods inside your gallery model to do this. Although you can require the libraries needed to allow you to load and invoke a rake task, it's really not the right thing to do in most, if not all cases. It's just not what rake was built for.